# Is the FAQ wrong re: the ability to vote to close a question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close

In comments, a user with a rep of 827 said he didn't see the `close` link under a question.   But in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) it says

> **250** Vote to close, reopen, or migrate
>   your questions

Is the FAQ wrong?  Is that close link being hidden by mistake?

Comment: Could you link the instance you're referring to? As far as I know, this still works as it should, so it is likely that there is something specific to the question or user at hand that is the cause of this.

Comment: Nevermind, found the user - you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350581/how-many-rows-are-too-many-for-a-mysql-table), correct? Searching through your own comment history probably would've been a lot faster than searching through all of the users with 827 reputation (which are page 442-443, for the curious).

Comment: you trust an 827 rep user more than OUR GLORIOUS FAQ? For shame. *For shame!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user with 827 should **not** see a close link under a question.  Unless it is their own.

- 250   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate **your** questions
- 1000  Show total up and down vote counts
- 3000  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions

Comment: This is the answer. [The user who asked about the closing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/307138/ocaso-protal) is not the [person who asked the question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/459537/happydeveloper), which means 3000 reputation is needed.

Comment: I don't reading comprehension much.

Answer (score 4):

Was it *his own question*, or someone elses? Or perhaps it was a question he posted under a different account and he needs them merged.

Comment: Gotta love the somewhere-between-reasonable-and-wild speculation that takes place when there aren't enough details.

Comment: @Popular: I do what I can. ;)